# Changing layout and adding titles to JSON file with python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to extract data from two different api endpoints and create a JSON file with said data. I wish to have titles for each object to distinguish the different data. My code is below:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

dataAAPL = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/insider-trades?limit=15&type=ALL&sortColumn=lastDate&sortOrder=DESC', 
headers=headers).json()['data']['numberOfSharesTraded']['rows'][3]

dataMSFT = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/MSFT/insider-trades?limit=15&type=ALL&sortColumn=lastDate&sortOrder=DESC', 
headers=headers).json()['data']['numberOfSharesTraded']['rows'][3]

with open('AAPL_insider_piechart.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dataAAPL, f, indent=4)
    json.dump(dataMSFT, f, indent=4)
```

And this is the output JSON:

```
{
    "insiderTrade": "Net Activity",
    "months3": "(1,317,881)",
    "months12": "(1,986,819)"
}
{
    "insiderTrade": "Net Activity",
    "months3": "185,451",
    "months12": "31,944"
}
```

What I need, is for the JSON to look something like this:

```
{
    "AAPL":[
        {
            "insiderTrade": "Net Activity",
            "months3": "(1,317,881)",
            "months12": "(1,986,819)"
        }
    ],
    
    "MSFT":[
        {
            "insiderTrade": "Net Activity",
            "months3": "185,451",
            "months12": "31,944"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dictionary and place the two values in it before dumping it as JSON.

**Solution**

```py
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com/',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

dataAAPL = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/insider-trades?limit=15&type=ALL&sortColumn=lastDate&sortOrder=DESC', 
headers=headers).json()['data']['numberOfSharesTraded']['rows'][3]

dataMSFT = requests.get('https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/MSFT/insider-trades?limit=15&type=ALL&sortColumn=lastDate&sortOrder=DESC', 
headers=headers).json()['data']['numberOfSharesTraded']['rows'][3]

with open('AAPL_insider_piechart.json', 'w') as f:
     obj = {
            "AAPL": [dataAAPL],                               
            "MSFT": [dataMSFT]                            
    }
    json.dump(obj, f, indent=4)
```